# What are the sites that do not support iframing?

Tags: iframe, security, facebook-iframe, cross-site

I'm dynamically generating iframes for a number of random websites, and I'd love to know which sites do not support iframing so I can fall back to a thumbnail image. I already know sites like Facebook, Twitter, and Youtube don't support iframing, but I was wondering if anyone had hold of a more comprehensive list.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect any security-aware major site to disable iframes because they open up the possibility of [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) attacks.

Comment: is there a way to programmatically check if a site blocks iframing?

Comment: Use a browser remote control framework (something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)). Load the site into an iframe, and check after a couple seconds if it is still there.

Comment: sorry, I don't quite follow. Why would I be using Selenium?

Comment: How would you programatically check browser behavior otherwise?